# Can't modify elements inside a form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to write a simple page that posts to itself via an ajax call and populates some elements with selected elements from the response. It's working fine for pulling from elements outside the form (#testDiv and #testDiv2), but it doesn't work for elements inside the form (#testDiv3 and #testDiv4). I'm thinking I'm not selecting them correctly, they need some different syntax because they're inside the form, even though they're not inputs, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ajax_same_2.php</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="ajax_same_2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testDiv"><p>random number: <?php echo rand(0,100); ?></p></div>
    <div id="testDiv2"><p>...</p></div>
    <form id="userform" action="ajax_same_2.php" method="post">
        <div id="testDiv3"><p>take ajax test data from here</p></div>
        <div id="testDiv4"><p>put ajax test data here</p></div>
        <input type="submit" name="userSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userform').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                var $response=$(data);
                var $test = $response.filter('#testDiv').html();
                $('#testDiv2').html($test);
                var $test2 = $response.filter('#testDiv3').html();
                $('#testDiv4').html($test2);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `.filter` should be `.find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `.find`, not `.filter`. `.filter` just returns elements of the collection that match the selector; in this case, `$(data)` returns a collection of all the top-level elements in the returned `<body>`. `.find` searches descendants of the elements.

What you should do is wrap everything in a `DIV`, then use `.find`:

```
success: function(data) {
    var $response = $('<div>', { html: data });
    var $test = $response.find('#testDiv').html();
    $('#testDiv2').html($test);
    var $test2 = $response.find('#testDiv3').html();
    $('#testDiv4').html($test2);
}
```

You need the `DIV` because `.find` won't match the top-level elements themselves, it only searches descendants. So you to make everything a descendant of `$response`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) form:

```
success: function(data) {
    var $response = $(data);
    var $test = $('#testDiv', $response).html();   // here
    $('#testDiv2').html($test);
    var $test2 = $('#testDiv3', $response).html(); // and here
    $('#testDiv4').html($test2);
}
```